# Converting Altium STP/STL model into solidwork

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication, 3d

I need my STP/STL model to be re-captured in the 3D workspace environment from Altium to SolidWorks.

Can any one help me on this and can it indeed be done?
Norman

Answer (score 1):

You can import the 3D STP model of the PCB into Solidworks but I don't think the features will be editable. Just RTFM and it should work, but as I recall it was a bit quirky (maybe some holes were not quite open, that sort of thing).

There's supposed to be a new capability that allows editable features to be imported, according to some Solidworks sales guys that gave us a presentation (on another related product) last week. Not sure if it's extra cost or standard in the latest versions.

Comment: I import step files from Altium into Solidworks all the time, and provided the models in Altium don't have errors (overlapping solids, for example) you can run the feature recognition tool in SW and edit the features.

Comment: @derstrom8 Thanks. Do you know what the sales guys were referring to? We're using older versions of both SW and Altium (if it ain't broke..)

Comment: I expect it was the feature recognition tool, which is part of FeatureWorks. I think this was introduced in SolidWorks 2014. I don't remember having it in SW 2011 (the version I had before '14). Now I'm using '15 and love it.

Comment: @derstrom8 Thanks, we're back in 2011 with one even older seat.